# Issues with docker 1.2

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, docker, lxc, linux-containers

I'm trying to use docker version 1.2 and I'm having issues with it. When I restart the service it says running but when I run docker images (even with sudo) it gives me this error.

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?

I have added this export to my bashrc

> export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:4243

I have tried uninstalling existing docker versions as well but i still see docker and docker-1.0.0 in my bash autocomplete.

Comment: See the end of this [issue](https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/88). Have you tried to put 'DOCKER_OPTS' as described?

Comment: Guess that's more of a OSX issue. Thanks but that didn't help. It's got to do with the hosting providers configuration .They currently don't support docker 1.2 in their system.